# How to 'click' querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Reading the title you could think that it is easiest question ever, but it ain't so. Problem: I have to use the `click()` method on `querySelectorAll`. As I found in Google, it does have the method in the library, but once I wrote the next code I got an error:

```
const gsdCaseNewBtn = $("#someId")
const gsdCaseOldButton = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="SomeValue Case"]')
gsdCaseNewBtn.click(() => {
     gsdCaseOldButton[0].click()
})
```

So, as you can see, I'm creating a new button and trying to attach to it the 'onclick' behavior of already existing button. Method `click()` doesn't work with the error ("this method does not exist on type ..."). I tried to resolve the issue with `addEventListener`, but I don't need to set the `onclick` behavior of the old button, I just have to get it. Do someone has the idea how to get this code work?

Requirements: `gsdCaseOldButton` **can't** be of jQuery type. `gsdCaseNewBtn` can be any type.

Comment: Define a function for the click event, loop in gsdCaseOldButton and set the event for each button

Comment: You definitely can't click a HTMLCollection which lives in JavaScript.

Comment: The code in your question works fine given the right configuration: https://jsfiddle.net/a23q9o07/. What does your HTML look like, and what are you excpecting the raised click event to do?

Comment: @Teemu they're getting the `[0]` element from the NodeList

Comment: I dont see any problem with your code.

Comment: why are you using jquery and then not jquery?

Comment: If you're only ever going to use the first element, use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`...

Comment: There is no reason for gdsCaseOldButton to `not be able to be` of jQuery type. If you have a library already imported, you can use it. In either way this code should work

Comment: There are likely no elements that match the selector `'input[value="SomeValue Case"]'` in the DOM at the point you're calling the code. Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: Okay, if I will do it without JQuery, like this: `const gsdCaseNewBtn = document.querySelector("#someId")
    const gsdCaseOldButton = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="SomeValue Case"]')
    gsdCaseNewBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
         gsdCaseOldButton[0].click();
    });`  click() still not working

Comment: @TirelessCoder Did you try the link Rory provided [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56443571/how-to-click-queryselectorall#comment99480724_56443571)?  It should work just fine. Without more information we wont be able to help you.

Comment: My code does not crash. Just when i'm writing the `click()` method, VS Code underlines it with red and giving an error "Property 'click' does not exist on type 'Element'." But as I understand, the click property should be on this type

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan In the code, yes, but all the text in the question is talking about "clicking on querySelectorAll" ...

Comment: @Ivar @Rory McCrossan   I tried the Rory's code, `click()` method it is still underlined with red. Maybe it something with my VS code?

Comment: If you're using VS Code ignore JS intellisense. It's garbage. Check the code within a browser.

Answer (score -1):

This should fix your code:

```
<script>
    const gsdCaseNewBtn = document.querySelector("#someId")
    const gsdCaseOldButton = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="SomeValue Case"]')
    gsdCaseNewBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
         gsdCaseOldButton[0].click();
    });
</script>
```

I tested this in localhost ( I did not have access to Jquery) so i am not certain what the cause of the problem was.

Please let me know if this fixed your code.

Comment: Hi Jasper. I think you did not understand me in a right way. Method click() on `gsdCaseOldButton[0].click()` doesn`t work, it is giving error, and I can not understand why